# Regex - matching patterns without brackets

Tags: c#, regex

for example I have this string :

```
ABCDFFFE[_]XXX[_]O0[_]%[TT]__
```

What I want do achive is, match/change all _ into ?, and % into *, but NOT ! those inside brackets. The last thing is to remove bracket, but I could make it by string replace.

So my output after regex should be like this :

```
ABCDFFFE[_]XXX[_]O0[_]*[TT]??
```

and after string replace (or maybe it could be done with regex too)

```
ABCDFFFE_XXX_O0_%TT__
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can brackets be nested?

Comment: No, they can't be nested.

Comment: What about ABC[_, or ABC[DEF_GHI]?

Comment: ABC[DEF_GHI] --> ABC[DEF_GHI] It can't touch nothing inside brackets. Bracket will be removed at last step (but it could be string replace). ABC[_ --> ABC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `[...]` texts cannot be nested, you can use the following regex:

```
(\[[^][]*])|[_%]
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5C%5B%5B%5E%5D%5B%5D*%5D)%7C%5B_%25%5D&i=ABCDFFFE%5B_%5DXXX%5B_%5DO0%5B_%5D%25%5BTT%5D__)

It will capture `[...]` subtexts into Group 1 (so that we can restore them in the replacement result later) and just matches `_` or `%`.

Use it in the code like this:

```
var s = "ABCDFFFE[_]XXX[_]O0[_]%[TT]__";
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"(\[[^][]*])|[_%]", m =>
            m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[1].Value : m.Value == "_" ? "?" : "*");
```

The `m` match evaluator block checks if the Group 1 was matched, and if yes, we insert `m.Groups[1].Value`. If not, we check the `m.Value`: if it is `_`, replace with `?` (see `m.Value == "_" ? "?"`), if not - replace with `*`.

**UPDATE**

To obtain Result #2, the string without `[` and `]`, you can use

```
var result = Regex.Replace(te, @"(\[([^][]*)])|[_%]", m =>
            m.Groups[1].Success ? m.Groups[2].Value : m.Value == "_" ? "?" : "*");
```

The pattern `(\[([^][]*)])|[_%]` will capture the whole `[...]` into Group 1 and the contents inside it into Group 2. If Group 1 matches, Group 2 is initialized and we can refer to it with `m.Groups[2].Value`.

**See [IDEONE demos for both solutions](https://ideone.com/Yu9TcN)**

Comment: If I run it I get result `"ABCDFFFE[_]XXX[_]O0[_]*[TT]??"`

Comment: `ABCDFFFE[_]XXX[_]O0[_]*[TT]??` is what I copied/pasted now from my Text Visualizer in VS. **[Here is an `IDEONE` demo](https://ideone.com/Yu9TcN)**

Comment: nvm didn't see OP will replace the `[]` with `String.Replace()`. My apologies

Comment: I did not notice: `ABCDFFFE_XXX_O0_%TT__` is also an expected output?

Comment: Yes eventually he wants that as output, but he will remove the brackets with `String.Replace`

Comment: Yeah, maybe the `%` in the expected output #2 is a typo.

Comment: @AlexanderDerck you have rigth. Remaining brakets are easiest thing to remove :)

Comment: There is a way to remove them with that regex of mine. Just use one more capturing group. I updated the answer with another solution to obtain Result#2. Pozdrawiam Katowice!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - It works like a charm :) Thank you for your help ! Greetings from Katowice :)

Answer (score 1):

If you already know that each opening bracket has a closing bracket *(brackets are balanced)*, you can test if a closing bracket doesn't follow with a negative lookahead:

```
var result = Regex.Replace(s, @"[_%](?![^\]\[]*\])", m => m.Value == "_" ? "?" : "*");
```